# R - Overcoming Loading failed for 'x64' Error

Tags: r

I am having an issue trying to install R packages. I have tried changing my lib path from a shared folder to a system folder, however, this did not work.

Having difficulty understanding why the installation is failing. Can someone please help me? See error below:

```
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
evaluate 0.20 0.23 FALSE
knitr 1.42 1.45 FALSE

installing the source packages ‘evaluate’, ‘knitr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/evaluate_0.23.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 28346 bytes (27 KB)
downloaded 27 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/knitr_1.45.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 898762 bytes (877 KB)
downloaded 877 KB

installing source package 'evaluate' ...
** package 'evaluate' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
converting help for package 'evaluate'
finding HTML links ... done
create_traceback html
evaluate html
flush_console html
inject_funs html
is.message html
line_prompt html
new_output_handler html
parse_all html
remove_hooks html
replay html
set_hooks html
try_capture_stack html
watchout html
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'x64'
removing 'C:/R/win-library/4.1/evaluate'
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘evaluate’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'evaluate' is not available for package 'knitr'
removing 'C:/R/win-library/4.1/knitr'
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\lsullivan\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6lVp70\downloaded_packages’ removing 'C:/R/win-library/4.1/evaluate' Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘evaluate’ had non-zero exit status ERROR:
> dependency 'evaluate' is not available for package 'knitr' removing
> 'C:/R/win-library/4.1/knitr' Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status The
> downloaded source packages are in
> ‘C:\Users\lsullivan\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6lVp70\downloaded_packages’
```